# Child element click is not working due to top and position of parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to close the parent div when I click on 'Close' child div.

```
<div class="siblings"/>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" ng-click="handleClick()">Close</div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>

.parent {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}

.child {
    float: right;
}

.siblings {
    position: fixed;
    height: 66px;
}
```

I cant use pointer-events: none on my parent, as it contain links and other clickable data.
Also my sibling height is overlapping with my child div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What JS have you tried?

Comment: That seems an issue with css only.

Comment: Shouldn't you add `pointer-events: none;` to the `.siblings` instead of `.parent`?

Comment: I don't get what is the issue? Is it because `.siblings {
    position: fixed;}` ???  FYI, this is invalid `<div class="siblings"/>`. Is `siblings` element wrapping `parent` element or what?!

Comment: This seems like a CSS question rather than a JQuery issue.  I think you may want to rephrase.

Comment: Yes this is a CSS issue. It looks like parent's sibling height is overlapping on my child element and due to that any click on child 'Close' is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do since you are using JQuery:

```
$(".child").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideToggle();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rhaqaszk/)

Comment: How is it answering question???  And using angularjs, i wouldn't use that for sure (even i'm not angular dev but just guessing...)

Comment: @A.Wolff "I want to close the parent div when I click on 'Close' child div."...the above code closes the parent when the child is clicked I suppose...?

Comment: Ya ok, i was thinking OP was already using some code in `handleclick` method and issue was more regarding: `Also my sibling height is overlapping with my child div`. So it just looks like click event isn't fired and so this answer doesn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using Angular?

Then try like following
you can use ng-if or ng-show.

```
<div class="parent" ng-if="!obj.hideParent">
    <div class="child" ng-click="obj.hideParent=true">Close</div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

There are two reason here is that for ng-if is not working.

1. One is if we doesn't declare it in the scope already, this will not reflect.
2. Or the hideParent property value may be in string. So if it is in string, then this will not be considered as false or null.

You can do it in two different way to resolve this.

1. In controller, declare it in scope variable before accessing it in view, instead of dynamic variable

> $scope.obj={hideParent:null};

and make it true on button/div click

2. Declare a scope function in controller and access the variable there.

> ```
> $scope.HideParent= function (obj){
>     if(!obj){
> obj.hideParent=true;
> }
> else{
> $scope.obj={hideParent:true};
> }
> }
> ```

Here don't forget to send object to the function. If you send the property, obviously this won't reflect in view.

Comment: Here ng-click is not getting called because of CSS issue

Comment: I don't know the reason. But sometime the issue is occurring if we were not declared the object in the scope. So declare the object in the scope first and try to access that in html page, they this will reflect.

Answer (score 1):

> I cant use pointer-events: none on my parent, as it contain links and
>   other clickable data.

If you use `pointer-events: none` in parent then child div will not receive click event. Also, `pointer-events: none` will not allow any click but it will also not close parent div.

> Also my sibling height is overlapping with my child div.

It's because of mixing `position` style. At one place you used `position: relative;` and at other `position: fixed;`. If you want to do so, take a parent of both whose style will control natural behavior and bonding between these `div`.

> I want to close the parent div when I click on 'Close' child div.

```
<div class="parent" ng-if="!hideParent">
    <div class="child" ng-click="hideParent = true">Close</div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```